# Conditional outer tag in a directive (i.e. <strong>)

Tags: angularjs, directive

I like a directive that conditionally puts a tag outside some content (but always prints the content), like this:

```
<p><strong ng-if-always-keep-inner-content="model.condition">{{model.text}}</strong>/p>
```

so if condition is true I get

```
<p><strong>yada yada</strong></p>
```

otherwise I get

```
<p>yada yada</p>
```

I could write it myself, but I want to know if it is possible to do with built in directives/options.

I should perhaps say this is used together with Bootstrap, which afaiu recommends using <strong> vs some class with a bold font.

Comment: Unfortunately, I think that you have to do it yourself.

Comment: Here I am 2 years later with the same question. Did you make that directive to share with me yet? :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't think there is a built in directive. You should write it.

I suggest to use a classic ng-if

```
<p ng-if="model.condition"><strong>{{model.text}}</strong></p>
<p ng-if="!model.condition">{{model.text}}</p>
```

In your specific case, you can also use `ng-class` and set the strong style via css.

Comment: Thanks, yea. The reason for not using ng-class is simply b/c bootstrap recommends the tag, and I thought it'd be good to not add a cssrule for the same thing. So I think it could be a useful directive - "optional outer tag".